How to put a shapeGeometry background image in threejs
I searched various places and did not get the results i wanted. Thre reason why I changed gemetry to shape is that the position of each vertext of the obect, that is. the value in points can be changed by user, and different shape will apper denpending on thre changed points value.
class Shape extends THREE.Shape {
  constructor({ points }) {
    const shape = super();
    shape.moveTo(points[0].x, -points[0].z); 
    for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      shape.lineTo(points[i].x, -points[i].z);
    }
    shape.lineTo(points[0].x, -points[0].z); 

    return shape;
  }
}

const shape = new Shape({
  points: [
    { x: 0, y: 1, z: 0 },
    { x: 100, y: 1, z: 0 },
    { x: 100, z: 100, y: 1 },
    { x: 0, y: 1, z: 100 },
  ],
});

var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/10/21/22/00/chain-8332727_1280.jpg"
);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: texture });
var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
object.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(object);

const animate = () => {
  // controls.update();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  composer.render();
  if (controls.enabled) {
    controls.update();
  }
  D3Walls.forEach((w) => {
    w.visible =
      currentPosition.copy(w.position).sub(camera.position).lengthSq() >
      camera.position.lengthSq();
  });
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();


The two pictures above are the result of putting an image on the image's network tab and its object.
I created an object using shapeGeometry based on points made up of coordinates ([{x,y:1,z}]...) as follows: Try to put a background image into the object by putting an arbitrary image in the map of this shapeGeometry's material. However, the background image does not appear. Why?
